# Probability of a random subset of Z

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I'm stuck in this question, could someone give me a hand? I'll post what I've done so far.

Question 9:
Let $A=(1,2,3,4)$ and $Z=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$, if a subset B of Z is selected by chance calculate the probability of:

a) $P(B⊂A)$ B is a proper subset of A

$(3/10)*(2/10)*(1/10) =3/500$ of chance

b)$P(A∩B=Ø)$ A intersection B =empty set

$(2/10)*(3/10)*(4/10)*(5/10)*(6/10)=9/1250$

Is it correct?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll edit the qustion

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format numbers and math expressions.

Comment: How (accoring to which distributin) is the random subset selected? Uniformly over all subsets?

Comment: B is randomly selected from Z

Answer (score 1):

A better approach for a is to ask how many subsets $Z$ has and how many proper subsets of $A$ there are.  Similarly for b you want a subset of $A^c$.  How many of those are there?

Comment: subsets of Z: 2^10-1=1023 and A=2^4-1=15  but B is selected randomly from Z.

Comment: No, there are $1024$ subsets of $Z$.  The empty set should count, as should all of $Z$, as the problem does not exclude them.  Yes, there are $15$ proper subsets of $A$.  $B$ is randomly selected from the $1024$ subsets, so the chance is $15/1024$

Comment: So for a)P(B⊂A), the answer would be 15/1024 and for b)P(A∩B=Ø), the answer would be 1024 ? I don't get it

Comment: No, for $A \cap B = \emptyset$ you need $B$ to not include any of $1,2,3,4$, so it need to be a subset of $\{5,6,7,8,9,10\}$

Comment: So should I calculate the number of subsets of ${5,6,7,8,9,10}=2^6-1=63$ or should I multiply the chance of any element int the set like 2/10*3/10 like I did in the original question?

Comment: Your approach to the original question did not make sense.  Part b is just like part a except there are six elements that can be part of $B$ instead of four.  Again, you should not be subtracting $1$-both the empty set and all six elements count.

Comment: Ok so just to confirm: Subset of z are 2^10=1024 and subsets of A are $2^4-1=15 $ and for question a)$P(B⊂A)=15/1024$ and b)$P(A∩B=Ø)=16/64$  ? I was using $2^n-1$ because question a) asks for a proper subset

Comment: Yes, for a you want 15 because of the proper subset requirement.  For b, you are again choosing a random subset of $Z$, of which there are $1024$.

Comment: for b)(A∩B=Ø) =16/64 or 16/1024? what is the right answer?

Comment: Neither.  It is $64/1024$ because there are $2^6=64$ subsets of a $6$ element set, which is $A^c$ and $2^{10}=1024$ subsets of $Z$

Comment: And for a)(⊂)=15/1024 right?

Comment: That is correct.  I said that last time.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your help and patience